# How to combine multiple Welch's t test results

Tags: t-test, pooling

I have developed 4 biological indices for different pond types that have different sample sizes:

Index-1 is comprised of all 34 pond sites sampled in the study (15 least-disturbed sites and 19 impaired sites);
Index-2 is comprised of 6 least-disturbed salt ponds and 19 impaired sites;
Index-3 is comprised of 4 least-disturbed reed ponds and 19 impaired sites; and
Index-4 is comprised of 5 least-disturbed grass ponds and 19 impaired sites.

I would like to compare the performance of Index-1 (which includes all the different pond types) to each Index -2,-3, -4. But comparing Index-1 to Index-2, -3, and -4 is strongly affected by sample size differences.

For this reason **I would like to combine/pool the performance results for Index-2, -3, and -4 and then I will be able to compare the combined result for Index-2, -3, and -4 to Index-1 performance results.**

There is one performance test in which I would like to combine/pool the results for Index-2, -3, and -4:

1) **Responsiveness test** – this was measured as a) the absolute value of the difference in mean index values between the reference and impaired sites, and b) **as the Welch’s t-test value comparing those means.**

**Does anyone have any suggestions or guidance on how to combine the results of the  Welch’s t-test values?**